# Shift key stays "pressed" in Gnome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, gnome, vnc

I have a Linux with Gnome 2.6.1 which runs a VNC server. I access it only through the VNC and the problem is that when I press the Shift key, it stays pressed (so a cursor movement causes  a text selection).

I tried different VNC viewers (remmina, realvnc, vncviewer) and they all behave the same. So I suspect the problem might be in Gnome itself but I haven't been able to figure out where the problem is. Any ideas?